# python doesn't append each line but skips some

Tags: python, python-3.x, filewriter

I have a `complete_list_of_records` which has a length of 550

this list would look something like this:

1. Apples
2. Pears
3. Bananas

The issue is that when i use:

```
 with open("recordedlines.txt", "a") as recorded_lines:
      for i in complete_list_of_records:
            recorded_lines.write(i)
```

the outcome of the file is 393 long and the structure someplaces looks like so

1. Apples
2. PearsBananas
3. Pineapples

I have tried with `"w"` instead of `"a"` append and manually inserted `"\n"` for each item in the list but this just creates blank spaces on every second row and still som rows have the same issue with dual lines in one.

Anyone who has encountered something similar?

Comment: It may be that some of the strings in your *complete_list_of_records" list have newline terminators and other do not. Check each string and write a newline where appropriate. The file open mode will not affect this. 'a' is for append (or create if missing) 'w' is for writing (or creating/overwriting)

Comment: @LancelotduLac do you have a code example on this?

Comment: Do any of the strings in *complete_list_of_records* have zero length or are all whitespace? If there are, how would you want to process them?

Comment: all strings in the list has values. some strings contain whitespaces in between chars.

like so:

`hello.    world`
`0000helloworld000`
`he1239239world``

Comment: for some reason stackoverflow removes whitespaces in comments but imageine like 20 whitespaces after hello and before world

Comment: If any of the strings in *complete_list_of_records* contain newline characters (and I think they do from what you've said elsewhere), how would you want those to look in the output file?

Comment: here is a screenshot that shows what each line can look like
https://ibb.co/jfMNV0g

Comment: You have shown us a redacted form of your data ("looks like so") but the problem is that your data is not really exactly as you think it is, and maybe not exactly what your text editor is showing you. As another comment has suggested, it may have inconsistent line endings. Open it in Notepad++ (free) to see what is really in the file.

Comment: notepad ++ for mac doesn't exist unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments seen so far, I think there are strings in the source list that contain newline characters in positions other than at the end. Also, it seems that some strings end with newline character(s) but not all.

I suggest replacing embedded newlines with some other character - e.g., underscore.

Therefore I suggest this:

```
with open("recordedlines.txt", "w") as recorded_lines:
      for line in complete_list_of_records:
            line = line.rstrip() # remove trailing whitespace
            line = line.replace('\n', '_') # replace any embedded newlines with underscore
            print(line, file=recorded_lines) # print function will add a newline
```

Comment: then i just replaced all the "_" with " "

Answer (score 1):

You could simply strip all whitespaces off in any case and then insert a newline per hand like so:

```
with open("recordedlines.txt", "a") as recorded_lines:
    for i in complete_list_of_records:
        recorded_lines.write(i.strip() + "\n")
```

Comment: This kind of works but not completely. Now i have 569 lines instead og 550, there are places where it strips and shouldn't

Comment: Could you provide an example? Are there lines that should be empty?

Comment: sure these lines are kind of strange looking, they can look like this:
`0000232323213231.              234234234234.        dfeeeer4r4.    3300`

Comment: What is stripped that shouldn't be stripped?

Comment: for instacne in the example above `dfeeeeer4r4`ends up in a new line

Comment: or rather actually `3300`because that is the last part of the line

Comment: Well, that could be because a "\n" is somewhere in the line?

Comment: What you could try is `i.strip().replace("\n", "")`

Comment: @rammelmueller Unfortunately, using strip() will also remove any leading whitespace which may not be desirable

Comment: Aha, how about `.rstrip()` then?

Comment: same output but now linecount is 566

Comment: Can you print the same line as above but use `repr(string)` instead? This let's you see the (potentially problematic?) whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use

```
file.writelines(listOfRecords)
```

but the list values must have '\n'

```
f = open("demofile3.txt", "a")
li = ["See you soon!", "Over and out."]
li = [i+'\n' for i in li]
f.writelines(li)
f.close()

#open and read the file after the appending:
f = open("demofile3.txt", "r")
print(f.read())
```

output will be

```
See you soon!
Over and out.
```

you can also use for loop with write() having '\n' at each iteration

Comment: this does not work. That is the whole issue.

Comment: The problem with this is that it does the exact same thing as appending everything with "a" or "w"